# Why does the serial value get printed twice along with a value that is not sent?

Tags: arduino, serial-port

Using the code below, I am trying to print the value that is received through the Arduino serial. But the value gets printed twice. And one among the printed values is always 0.

```cpp
byte b;
int i;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setTimeout(10);
}

void loop() {
  while(Serial.available() == 0) {}
  i = Serial.parseInt();
  Serial.println(i);
}

EXAMPLE: value sent is 15
Serial monitor output: 15
                       0

EXAMPLE: value sent is 99
Serial monitor output: 99
                       0
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because the first `i = Serial.parseInt();` prints the read value and returns 0 to the `i` variable, which means that the value was printed successfully.

On the second `Serial.println(i);`, you just print the `i` value, which was 0.

Comment: So how to avoid this? If it prints 0, the other function will not work. Say brightness, if value is 50 the brightness will be half the total. But when it gets 0, there will be no brightness.

Comment: Watch [this example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read). Actually your serial monitor is displaying the value that you write and the parseInt succesfull status.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are sending from the serial monitor with newline characters.

This is what is happening in your code.

1. You are sending `15\n`.
2. `Serial.parseInt()` reads `1` and `5` from the serial buffer and stops at `\n`. Then it returns `15`.
3. Because `\n` is still in the buffer, `Serial.parseInt()` gets called again.
4. `Serial.parseInt()` discards any non numerical character from the serial buffer, until it finds a numerical character.
5. It removed `\n` and waits for a numerical character.
6. `Serial.parseInt()` times out and returns `0`.

If you want to prevent your second `Serial.parseInt()` call, you should send the string without newline characters or empty the serial buffer like this:

```cpp
void loop() {
  while(Serial.available() == 0) {}
  i = Serial.parseInt();
  Serial.println(i);
  while(Serial.available() > 0) Serial.read(); // empty the serial buffer by reading everything from it
}
```